Can they do this?
If I'm homeless living in a tent and I mow for this guy and he offers his back yard to put my tent well a few weeks later after mowing and racking weekly for free and clearing back yard of trash and wasit high brush and grass(cause when I mowed prier he didn't want back yard mowed) he now says my loud coice,wakes him cause he sleeps all day and up all night (even tho he was up day before all day so I thought he got his days and nights back in order) my mouth at 1pm in the day woke him I had to leave ,we'll he then gave me two days to find a place to move tent ,we'll not even 24hrs later which is now he saying he can charge me for trespassing cause he has a sign on front door?? Can he do this and is it legal ? How am I trespassing when he gave me ne permission to be here?? And hasnt paid me for mowing and rack and not paid me at all nor for clearing the back yard and creek up???

You are asking for legal advice in a specific case. For legal reasons, Law SE cannot provide that. It can help people who want to learn about the law, which is a different thing. Also, it will make a big difference where this happened.

The legal interpretation will depend on where it happened. However:

You might have had a contract with this guy, allowing you the use of part of his property in exchange for work in the yard.
In many countries, rental contracts should be in writing. In the absence of a written contract, the standard rules for that country apply.
He may or may not have agreed to pay you money for your work in addition to the use of part of his property.

Such an agreement would never be forever, and this guy seems to want to terminate the agreement. How that works again depends on the country, and also on the details of the contract. It may be necessary for him to start formal eviction proceeding, or not.
